# regex for ftp url

Tags: php, ftp

how to have an regex expression that matches ftp url in the format of this

```
ftp://user:name@server
```

I have data in the format of the above and need to run preg_match to make sure that I only return data in the above format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use regex for this. Just use native [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) function.

```
function check_ftp_url($url){
    $p = parse_url($url);
    return isset($p['scheme'])&& !strcasecmp($p['scheme'], 'ftp')
           &&isset($p['host'])
            &&isset($p['user'])&&isset($p['pass']);
}
```

### Pros

1. It takes less time to write
2. You dont need to invest hours on regex to find a regex solution.
3. Its the proper way to check a url

### Cons

1. You'll need to write more characters than regex

Comment: This won't check to see if the scheme is FTP as HTTP auth can use the same format as OP is asking, but be HTTP scheme.

Comment: easily fixed by also checking $p['scheme']

Comment: @crypticツ right you are. I have update it. also added **pros and cons**. Feel free to point out anything I may be missing.